# Webpack modulesDirectories config

Tags: webpack

I am trying to configure modulesDirectories so that

`@import "~react-toolbox/lib/commons";`

works.

This is what I have right no for resolve.modulesDirectories:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.css', '.scss', '.js', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
```

I am presently getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/components/course/style.scss
Module build failed: File to import not found or unreadable: ~react-toolbox/lib/commons
Parent style sheet: stdin (1:1)
 @ ./src/components/course/style.scss 4:14-128 13:2-17:4 14:20-134
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Updated sass-loader to v3.2.0 - and problem solved.